# Como ler arquivos de texto?

Tags: c#

Eu quero ler as linhas de um arquivo e depois adicioná-las a um ListBox.

```
public void subroutine()
    {
        string linha;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "workers.txt", true));
            {
                do
                {
                    line = read.ReadLine;
                        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
                }
                while ((line = read.ReadLine()) != null);

            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "workers.txt", true);
        }
    }
```

> Erro:
>   "Read" não existe no contexto atual.

Comment: Não sei se é duplicata, mas a pergunta não é clara. Deu erro onde?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente colocar todas as linhas em um array e depois fazer um `foreach`. Não é necessário um `StreamReader`.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("workers.txt");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: Eu ia mesmo falar isso. Ótima resposta. _One-liner_ e ainda evita vazamento de recurso.